# CRM/helpdesk/billing/forum service (open source)

Tags: ecommerce

I developed an online service, subscription based (task management for a very specific niche).

I am looking to offer it for monthly fee.
I need a software recommendation, or a 'proven' combo of packages.

Features:

1. Billing, including invoices, etc (via outside party, braintree or
   similar)
2. Helpdesk/Customer interaction: Logs emails sent and received
3. Mail agent that sends reminders (subscription elapsing, offers, etc), where I can edit templates, scripts, etc, based on user profile, and date
4. Forum for discussion about features
5. FAQ (can be integrated in forum)
6. Account history including transactions

The service itself is asp.net, and uses Membership model. So integration is important.

Any suggestions?